# Sql query max, group by

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I am trying to get all students group by class_id, student_id, teacher_id
SO what I mean is this one :

```
Select id,class_id, student_id,teacher_id, max(active)
                                 FROM student_classes
                                  GROUP BY class_id, student_id, teacher_id
```

But this is what I get
[image]

Actually what I want as a result is:

```
114   137  1  47  1
108   138  2  49  0
 113  197  3  47  1
```

So basically the problem is at the third row. Instead of having id = 113 I get ID=111.
What should I do in this case? Can you please help me with the query

Comment: Your `select` columns and `group by` columns are inconsistent.  The query should actually fail because `id` is not being aggregated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that depends on the RDBMS being used.  A good one will behave as you say, but some don't :)

Comment: @alpvel What RDBMS are you using?  Can you explain WHY 113 should be displayed on the third row rather than any other id value?

Comment: MySql, and it has to be 113 since this id has max(active) which is 1 in its group.

Comment: @DaveCosta I agree with Gordon. The query is malformed, even if the database engine is accepting it. Who knows what the engine is doing with it. Better to fix the query and sleep well.

Comment: @DaveCosta can you please help me with the query

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't think I said the query shouldn't be fixed.  I said it's not true that the query will fail in all RDBMS systems.

Comment: @DaveCosta . . . The query is malformed.  That some databases violate the standard (and good sense) to accept such queries does not make them "right".

Comment: In MySQL you should use `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode to help you write proper aggregation queries. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL versions 5.5, 5.6 works as you coded. But actually it's not correct. With version 5.7 and higher it will throw error. The error will be like *"SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'student_classes.id'..."*

Therefore it seems your DB version is old and maybe this code should work as you wanted

```
select 
    ---------
    min(x.id) as id, 
    ---------
    x.class_id, 
    x.student_id, 
    x.active
from student_classes x
 inner join (select 
                class_id, 
                student_id, 
                teacher_id, 
                ---------
                max(active) max_active 
                ---------
              from student_classes x 
              group by class_id, student_id, teacher_id
            )  y
    on x.class_id = y.class_id and 
        x.student_id = y.student_id and 
        x.teacher_id = y.teacher_id and 
        x.active = y.max_active
 group by x.class_id, x.student_id, x.active
 order by id, class_id, student_id
;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, MySQL allows something against the SQL standard, letting you include a non-aggregated column (in this case `id`) in the select list of a query that includes a `group by`.  As far as I know, it will arbitrarily pick one row in each grouping and display the `id` value from that row.

If you have a specific rule about which `id` value you want to see, you need to express that in your query.

By the way, your desired output appears to have multiple typos (e.g. 197, which doesn't appear in your data at all).

From your comment (which you should edit into your original question), and your desired output, I think the rule you want for the `id` column is:

- If there are any rows with active=1 in the group, choose the maximum id value from those rows
- If all rows in the group have active=0, choose the minimum id value.  (You didn't say this specifically; I'm assuming it based on the presence of 108 on the second row of your desired output.)

I think that this query will produce those results.  (And also eliminate the non-standard MySQL behavior.)

```
  SELECT
   COALESCE(
        MAX(CASE WHEN active=1 THEN id ELSE NULL END),
        MIN(id)
      ) AS some_id
   class_id, student_id, teacher_id, max(active)
  FROM student_classes
  GROUP BY class_id, student_id, teacher_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want an aggregation actually, but rather pick particular rows. The rule for picking a row is: Per `class_id, student_id, teacher_id` get the one with the maximum `active` and in case of a tie the lowest `id`. This is a ranking of rows.

As of MySQL 8 you can use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER` to rank rows:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    sc.*,
    row_number() over (partition by class_id, student_id, teacher_id
                       order by active desc, id) as rn
  from student_classes sc
) with_wanted_id
where rn = 1;
```

In older versions you could use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude rows for which a better row exists:

```
select *
from student_classes sc1
where not exists
(
  select null
  from student_classes sc2
  where sc2.class_id = sc1.class_id
    and sc2.student_id = sc1.student_id
    and sc2.teacher_id = sc1.teacher_id
    and
    (
      sc2.active > sc1.active
      or
      (sc2.active = sc1.active and sc2.id < sc1.id)
    )
);
```